How do I gradually slow down player rotation in unreal vr
I'm trying to make it so when the right stick is held in a direction to rotate the camera that way, it eases in and out to make it less jarring than being completely linear. What I have so far does the first part pretty well, but when I move the right stick back to 0, it will immediately stop instead of slowing down.

My guess is that the problem is the clamp value being 1 so that makes the bottom lerp node automatically choose B and I don't know how to make it ease into B at all since the part where the rotation eases in is possible from the elapsed seconds float value.
